# How to identify duplicate index in sql server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table with around 100 columns with total rows around 73 million.

```
e.g. Table(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,....Col100)

Composite Clusterd Index(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
Composite Non Clustered Index(Col25, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
```

Can we say Non clusted index is a duplicate index and we can fine tune the performance and storage by creating NC index only on Col25 and it will work the same way?

Answer (score 0):

You can run script to determine index usage for your DB:

```
select 
object_name(s.object_id) as table_name,
i.type_desc as index_type_desc,
case when s.index_id=0 then  '' else i.name end as index_name, 
s.user_seeks + s.user_scans + s.user_lookups as total_reads,
case when (s.user_seeks + s.user_scans + s.user_lookups)=0 then 0
else (convert(float,s.user_scans)) / (s.user_seeks + s.user_scans + s.user_lookups) * 100.00 end as scan_percentage,
s.user_updates as total_writes,
case when (s.user_seeks + s.user_scans + s.user_lookups)=0 then 0 else 
(convert(float,s.user_updates)) / (s.user_seeks + s.user_scans + s.user_lookups) * 100 end as writes_percentage,
ios.lock_count, ios.lock_wait_in_ms, ios.latch_wait_in_ms, ios.io_latch_wait_in_ms, ios.index_lock_promotion_count,
ph.avg_fragmentation_in_percent, ph.page_count
from 
sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s
left join  sys.indexes i on s.object_id=i.object_id and s.index_id=i.index_id
left join (
select 
database_id, object_id, index_id,
row_lock_count + page_lock_count as lock_count,
row_lock_wait_in_ms + page_lock_wait_in_ms as lock_wait_in_ms,
page_latch_wait_in_ms + tree_page_latch_wait_in_ms as latch_wait_in_ms,
page_io_latch_wait_in_ms + tree_page_io_latch_wait_in_ms as io_latch_wait_in_ms,
index_lock_promotion_count
from sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL)
where object_id>100 and database_id=DB_ID()
) ios on s.database_id=ios.database_id and s.object_id=ios.object_id and s.index_id=ios.index_id
left join(
select 
p.database_id,
p.object_id,
p.index_id,
p.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
p.page_count
from 
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),null,null,null,'limited') p
where 
p.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0
) ph on ph.database_id=s.database_id and ph.object_id=s.object_id and ph.index_id=s.index_id
where
s.database_id=DB_ID() and s.object_id>100 OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

where columns are:

- table_name
- index_type_desc: clustered, heap or nonclustered
- index_name
- total_reads
- scan_percentage: what percentage of reads was scans (bad query plan)
- total_writes
- writes_percentage: detects indexes that updates but not used (>100%)
- lock & latchs: show you single-user latency (latch) and multi-user latency (locks)
- avg_fragmentation_in_percent & p.page_count: tell you about index fragmentation (index health)

Run it and you can see how many times SQL uses your index1, index2, index3 etc.

In addition to your question, you'll see latency and maintenance cost of your indexes. At 73 millions records it is important values, I think.

Comment: I was created this script for my tool to tune up ERP systems.